# How to switch UIImages in UIViewController from Array by pressing UIButton

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

So I have a storyboard with UIImageView and two buttons and I need these buttons to change images in UIImageView. UIImages stored in an Array. I tried for in but it can show only only first image. Help would be appreciated :)

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var images: [UIImage] = [
UIImage.init(named: "2")!,
UIImage.init(named: "3")!,
UIImage.init(named: "4")!]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() }


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any){
    for el in images {
        imageView.image = el }
}}
```

Comment: It's shorter using `UIImage(name: "")` instead of  `UIImage.init(named: "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a "index" value to determine which image to show from your array of images.

Start at 0 (zero) to show the first image (arrays are zero-based).

When you click the "next" button, ***increment*** the index and update the imageView (but don't go beyond the number of images in your array).

When you click the "previous" button, ***decrement*** the index and update the imageView (but don't go below 0).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var images: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage.init(named: "2")!,
        UIImage.init(named: "3")!,
        UIImage.init(named: "4")!
    ]

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imageIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // updae the imageView with the first image
        imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // if we're at the end of the images array, just return
        if imageIndex == images.count - 1 {
            return
        }
        // increment the index
        imageIndex += 1
        // update the image view
        imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
    }

    @IBAction func prevButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // if we're at the start of the images array, just return
        if imageIndex == 0 {
            return
        }
        // decrement the index
        imageIndex -= 1
        // update the image view
        imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of for loop in your `@IBAction` you only see the last image set to your image view. for solution you can define a variable, with button action increase the value and set it to your array index to show in your image view.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = [UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3"), UIImage(named: "4")]
var actualImage = 0 // counter to know witch image is displayed

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    imageView.image = images[actualImage]

    if actualImage == images.count - 1 { // check if i'm at the last picture
        actualImage = 0 // reset the counter to the first position
    } else {
        actualImage += 1
    }
}
```